# Is there a reason that stack.imgur.com image resizing parameters don't work on certain images?

Tags: support, editing, images

In [an answer I just posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70879/80s-anime-with-mecha-having-tank-tread-roller-skates/194589#194589), it seems that stack.imgur.com is not resizing the images when the letters t or m are added to the filename. As an example, here's bUxeut.jpg and bUxeum.jpg:

[image]

[image]

You may confirm that the URL syntax is correct by editing this question or opening the above images individually. Currently, these display for me at the same size in the preview of this question. Past questions that I've used these image sizes in remain unaltered.

It's not ignoring all of the possible parameters, since image bUxeus.jpg and bUxeub.jpg display properly resized:

[image] 
[image]

I've changed the thumbnails to the large square size (b) in the answer in question. But I greatly prefer to include the t or m sizes in my answers, as they fit very nicely between paragraphs, with two side-by-side images fitting on one line without being cropped into squares. So if there's a reason why my images aren't resizing to those sizes, or a work-around that could fix this, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: [Related main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/398063). To put it simply and politely, it's a mess. And [related chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46097857#46097857) from when the bug appeared... With some, let's say, colorful words from Nick Craver.

Comment: @Jenayah Ah, ok, so if the solution is just "remember that the correct size is 320 pixels wide, and use HTML", that's perfectly fine by me!

Comment: Yes, that's how low we fell. Doing math and using HTML.

Comment: @Jenayah since I haven't used an inline HTML width and height attribute in such a long time, only CSS parameters, I actually forgot that I can only put the width in and trust it'll display proportionally.

Comment: Some of [the options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230362/239016) still work.

Comment: Because it's broked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's broken network-wide.

See this main meta post: [The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/278659).

Because it's very useful, I'll quote the answer there on a useful workaround using [HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites):

> Use markup like:
>
> ```
> [<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJrvX.png" width="320" height="30" alt="wide demo pic">][2]
>   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJrvX.png "Click for larger image."
> ```
>
> which yields:
>
> [image: wide demo pic]
>
> -- With:
>
> - a useful `alt` parameter
> - Hover text.
> - a convenient link to the image, full-sized.